# How to get callback from calling function inside variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have some Javascript code that is similar to the following:

```
var Requests = {
  get: function(search) {
    // HTTP request happens, returns data.
  }
}
```

I'm trying to invoke this somewhere else, like the following:

```
Requests.get('thing');
```

Although this is returning undefined because it's not waiting for the http request result. I'm wondering how I can defer this request until it's successful, or somehow check for a callback in the invoking code. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.

Comment: I was looking at how to properly do that, but couldn't figure out the correct syntax. Any ideas? @EduardoMelo

Answer (score 0):

You need a promise.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

```
var Requests = {
     get: function(search){
        return new Promise(resolve,reject){
           //if it does what you want
           if(data) resolve(data)
           else reject(error)
        }
     }
}
```

And then

```
Requests.get('thing').then('do something else')
```

The other option is to use await/async but that is not fully supported yet.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

The function can return a promise:

```
var Requests = {
  get: function(search) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       // call resolve in case of success, and reject in case of error
    })
  }
}

Requests.get('thing').then(
  function(response){
   // success
  },
  function(error){
   // something went wrong
  }
);
```

In the "then" method of a Promise object, you need to pass the two functions used when the promise is resolved or rejected.

For more information on Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise.